# Spring transaction annotation not working

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I'm using Spring 3.2.4 with JavaFX and wanted to implement a method, where the operations will be performed in a transaction. My code in the controller looks like this:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = { ServiceException.class,
            ValidationException.class })
    public void registerVolunteer(User user, Volunteer volunteer)
            throws ServiceException, ValidationException {
        User ret = userService.create(user);
        volunteer.setUser(ret);
        volunteerService.untransactedCreate(volunteer);
    }
```

And my application-context:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>

    <!-- Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

Trying to run this, I get this error message:

```
Controller method "onBackClicked" not found.
/home/workspace/project/NewProject/target/classes/fxml/RegisterVolunteer.fxml:69
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:497)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:594)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2472)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2177)
  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2069)
  at org.impactvolunteers.management.FXMLSpringLoader.load(FXMLSpringLoader.java:97)
  at org.impactvolunteers.management.FXMLSpringLoader.load(FXMLSpringLoader.java:81)
  at org.impactvolunteers.management.gui.Screen.init(Screen.java:50)
  at org.impactvolunteers.management.gui.ScreensController.init(ScreensController.java:43)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  ...
```

The method exists. With either removing the annotation, or changing the method from `public` to `private` or removing the bean from the config, the program runs but the `@Transactional`-annotation simply would not work. Removing `proxy-target-class="true"` leads me to another error.

Comment: Your error message is unrelated to the transactional annotation. You might notice in your stacktrace that you have no reference to the Spring application context at all. Proxying the target class using CGLIB is only required if your services isn't implementing an interface. Your exception is saying that JavaFX can't find a controller method. Is that controller annotated with `@Controller` and do you have `<mvc:annotation-driven>` in your Spring XML?

Comment: I moved the method to a separate service class and this fixed the problem. I did not have both of these, cause I'm developing a native app with JavaFX and I am not using the MVC. The error message is not related to the annotation, but changing the method from public to private removed the error message, which appeared weird to me, but I am not very informed about the specifics of Spring so...

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about `@Transactional` then it is used to rollback the Current Transaction Happen.

That is mostly used in Making Test Cases, Let me show you :

```
RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "txManager",defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public class AddVendorProcessorTest{

   // Your code
}
```

now here in `@TransactionConfiguration` it takes `transactionManager` from here, an XML file :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db"/>
    <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
    <property name="password" value="pwd"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.domain"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="txManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
```

it will automatically get `txManager` bean.

Still if any query POST me.

Comment: Again, I am not using the MVC. Controller means in my case JavaFX Controller.